# TFS build adding an unwanted code block to xap file Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, msbuild, unity-container

Here is a list of my references in my silverlight project.

```
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight<br/>
mscorelib<br/>
Prospector.ProviderMatching.LinkedDataObjects<br/>
Prospector.ProviderMatching.SLDataObjects<br/>
System<br/>
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations<br/>
System.Core<br/>
System.Net<br/>
System.ServiceModel<br/>
System.Windows<br/>
System.Windows.Browser<br/>
System.Windows.Controls<br/>
System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input<br/>
System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit<br/>
System.Windows.Data<br/>
System.Xml<br/>
```

When I build the project localy the contence of my xap file looks like the following.

AppManifest.xaml
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll
   Prospector.ProviderMatching.DataObjects.SL.dll
   Prospector.ProviderMatching.Silverlight.dll
   Prospector.ProviderMatching.SLDataObjects.dll
   ServiceReferences.ClientConfig
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals.dll
   System.Windows.Data.dll

When this is checked in and the build server kicks off it creates a xap file with the following contence.

AppManifest.xaml
   **Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll**
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll
   Prospector.ProviderMatching.DataObjects.SL.dll
   Prospector.ProviderMatching.Silverlight.dll
   Prospector.ProviderMatching.SLDataObjects.dll
   ServiceReferences.ClientConfig
   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll
   System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals.dll
   System.Windows.Data.dll

As you can see I have gained a code block in the xap file that the application does not use.  However not only is this a waste of bandwidth, it actually prevents the silverlight app from doing anything, it is downloaded but does not run.

If I remove the offending Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator.dll from the xap file and the manifest.xml the silvlight app then functions as intended.

Has anyone got any ideas why the build server is including this library and how to prevent it from doing so...?

Comment: Just a  thought...are you using Prism?  Have you checked that you are not using the wrong assemblies (maybe the WPF ones?)

Comment: I think Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll keeps getting added as you have a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll
I have a feeling that they are dependent on each other.  Are you using Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll keeps getting added as you have a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll I have a feeling that they are dependent on each other. Do you need to use Unity?  As to why your app fails when Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll is included in the XAP; I have a suspicion that you may be using the wrong version of the Microsoft.Practices.Servicelocation.dll (WPF version?)

Comment: Thank you for you feed back.  I do not have a reference to Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll in my solution at all, so I don't know how I would make it use the right one.  I only have a reference to Mirosoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll.  If ServiceLocation was a dependecy of Unity.Silverlight then why would it not be included in the xap build locally by visual studio?

Comment: I use Unity on Silverlight projects here. I've just added a reference to Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll in one of my SL projects here. After doing a local build I opened up the XAP file and found.....Microsoft.Practices.Servicelocation.dll. I'm more interested in why your SL app fails when the XAP contains the Microsoft.Practices.Servicelocation.dll file. My SL apps run fine when the XAPs contain both DLLs. Whats the version number of the Microsoft.Practices.Servicelocation.dll that you are finding in your XAP. How does your app fail...are there error messages?

Comment: Just found this in my local build output:Dependency "Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". (TaskId:956)Required by "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight". (TaskId:956)

Comment: More confirmation: http://blog.johnclaytonmoore.com/post/Unity-for-Silverlight-and-XAMLParseException.aspx

Comment: Ok, I have disassembled Microsoft.Practices.unity.silverlight and it quite clearly has a dependency on ServiceLocation like you say.assembly extern Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation
{
  .publickeytoken = (31 BF 38 56 AD 36 4E 35 )                         // 1.8V.6N5
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}

Comment: So there is the answer (hint)! If you are going to be referencing Unity then the XAP will contain Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation. If you are concerned about the size of the XAP then you could always look at assembly caching....but that's another discussion.

Comment: I also disassembled the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll and it looks like it is the standard .net version (using version 2:0:0:0 of mscorlib).  It is very strange that Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll does not get included in the xap file when I build it locally.  I will look at explicitly adding a reference too the silverlight version in the morning to see if that will work.

Comment: Many thanks for your help Myles, i'll have to pick this up in the morning though, will post results of how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

Myles really got to the crucks of the matter and I just add this for more detail of my particular problem.

The problem was that the .net version of ServiceLocator was being built into the xap on the build server.

I think the reason it was not being built in locally was because it was being resolved by the GAC.

I took copies of the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.silverlight.dll and Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator.dll and added them to a shared binary folder which is checked into source control to which the build server can reference.  I then uninstalled Unity for Silverlight 2.0 from my installed programs (I assume this de-Gaced it).  I added references to the above dlls that were now in my binary folder and built my solution locally.  Hay presto I now have Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator.dll included in my xap file.

Once all this was checked into TFS the build now picked up the right version of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocator.dll from the shared binarys folder and included it in the xap.  Job done.  I think the cause of this problem lies in the Global Assembly Cache.

Hope this helps someone equally frustrated.

Comment: The unity installer does not GAC anything. Not sure how it got in there, some other program must have done it.